# Is perfume/cologne purchased from abroad "better" than if bought in the United States?

Tags: europe, shopping, duty-free

A friend told me that it is better to buy perfumes and/or cologne in Europe as opposed to the United States.

Her reasoning is that perfume/cologne that is sold in the US is water-based and contains more alcohol (by mandate) while a fragrance's European counterpart would be oil-based; producing richer scents that stay with your skin for a longer period of time. Her advice is to purchase from a duty free shop before heading back into the United States or at an EU department store.

For example and clarity: If I was to buy Terre d'Hermès at [Saks Fifth Avenue](http://www.saksfifthavenue.com/) in NYC does that bottle have the same formula and ingredients as Terre d'Hermès sold at [Liberty in London](http://www.liberty.co.uk/)?

Comment: About scents, per se, your question is way too broad. Which notes of the smell are you talking about ? As a matter of fact, how a perfume smells to the other person depends on the sweat and the type of sweat from the wearer of the perfume. First, I think your question is off topic. Second, you've gotta narrow down your question. The only oil based scents I know of is, Ittar. That is probably best purchased in the Arab world.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about perfume and its potential variation based on geography. While the answer might influence if you buy perfume while traveling, it isn't about travel per se.

Comment: This question appears to be on-topic because most people buy stuff to bring home, especially stuff not obtainable at home. All travel guides include this kind of information.

Comment: @hippietrail I am not sure I agree with your assessment I would put this question more inline with chemistry.SE site then this one.  More to the point, question is what is being compared? What criteria is being used?  Because other then anecdotal evidence I don't see anything.  In addition why would a chemical lab or plant producing the fragrance have 2 different lines.  One producing for Europe and another for the US.

Comment: @Karlson: I challenge you to put your reputation where your mouth is and post the question on the chemistry site without changint it to a different question. I am sure it will be closed. It seems clear to me that, at least after editing, the OP is asking if they can get "genuine" versions of name-brand perfumes in Europe that are not available in the US. Where "genuine" means the original formula containing volatile oils that seem to have been banned by government mandate in the US and replaced with a water base.

Comment: Quinsak, if the `duty free` tag is crucial to the question, why do you make no mention of it? Do you believe buying the perfume in a regular shop in Europe vs buying at a duty-free shop in an airport in Europe also has an effect on which ingredients it contains? Or are you also asking about the price or something? Is "Liberty in London" a duty-free shop?

Comment: Fully agree with @hippietrail here on all counts. This is on-topic!

Comment: You might compare it to buying *Guinness* in Ireland vs elsewhere because they actually have breweries around the world. The Guinness you buy in USA says "imported" on the label because the set up a brewery in Belize. It's the same reason I buy tequila just before I leave Mexico. Not just because it's cheaper than I can get in Australia, but because I know it's the real thing and not some crappy export variant tailored to foreign tastes.

Comment: The Guinness and tequila comparison is right on track.  That is what I am trying to get to the bottom of: are fragrance producers required to change aspects of their products ingredients based on where it will be sold?  The question is tagged "duty-free" because that is where many people shop for fragrances when traveling.

Comment: @happybuddha How does all that have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @Annoyed "Better" is a relative term. Which aspect of the scent in question is better ? I would love to answer any question on perfumes. But to me, if the OP is comparing scents and the betterness of them, the OP needs to give more details about the scents. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfume

Comment: @happybuddha But that's not really what the question is about. At the very least, it would be interesting to know if products sold under one name by major brands are typically identical in the US and Europe or not. If not, there could be some consensus among experts about the merits of different solvent/formulations/whatever or maybe some general rule of thumbs that are not entirely subjective. OTOH, if all this really is entirely subjective and down to the individual brand and personal preferences with no general rule then knowing that is a valuable answer. Either way, it's a valid question.

Comment: Thank you @Annoyed , that is the nature of the question.  It's not about the notes, just simply whether or not it is the same exact ingredients if purchased in two different locations (US vs. EU).

Comment: @Quinsak Do you know who will best be able to answer this question : If I was to buy Terre d'Hermès at Saks Fifth Avenue in NYC does that bottle have the same formula and ingredients as Terre d'Hermès sold at Liberty in London?  ? The makers of Terre. I still doubt if a question asking ingredients of a product available in two countries would constitute to be a travel question.

Comment: It's a broader question simply asking if there are US regulations/rules that force fragrance makers to change the ingredients of their perfumes/colognes to be sold in the US market.

Comment: For example the FDA has stricter rules on cheese production than other countries. Cheeses made with unpasteurized (raw) milk can not be sold in the US unless they have been aged for at least 60 days. This is regulated by the The FDA with the intention of protecting consumers from potentially harmful bacteria in unpasteurized milk. After 60 days, the acids and salts in raw-milk cheese naturally prevent listeria, salmonella, and E. coli from growing. In contrast European cheeses have traditionally been made with raw milk as no such 60 day law exists in their market.

Comment: @Quinsak Are you by chance comparing EDT to EDP or to Perfume itself?

Answer (score 3):

Ok.  Let's forget for the moment that we don't know if we are comparing [EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_toilette) to [EDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_Parfum) to [Parfum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eau_de_Parfum) itself, but let's assume that we are actually comparing Apples to Apples.

Speficically when it comes to Terre d'Hermes it has been [reformulated](http://www.basenotes.net/threads/307251-Terre-d-hermes-reformulated?s=0ee775d58d6e24fa73b819294e463961&p=2647927&viewfull=1#post2647927) due to restrictions imposed by [IFRA](http://www.fragrantica.com/news/Iso-E-Super-A-Very-Popular-Synthetic-2837.html) on [ISO E Super](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfume).  So if you bought it before the restriction and after you will definitely be buying a chemically different product.

There is no indication that there is an en masse difference between perfume products sold in Europe and the US.